# mod_rewrite masking queries for better SEO

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Im trying to make more `SEO` friendly directories in my site and need help with `mod_rewrite`. I always hate reg expressions.

I want to change urls like: `mysite.com/result.php?cat=Beach`

into

`mysite.com/category/beach` so that PHP still picks up the get without showing it in the header.

Comment: few thousand similar questions if you care to search. and the actual value in rewriting the urls for SEO  is limited

Comment: what have you tried? Did you look in the right panel for related questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^category\/(.+)$ result.php?cat=category&$1
```